# redis conf changes without restart

Tags: logging, redis

Sorry for a silly question, I want to change `logfile` and `loglevel` in redis without doing restart, if there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CONFIG SET` command to set the loglevel, setting the log file isn't supported.

See http://redis.io/commands/config-set for details